# C. Neumann passage in Latin from *Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata*

Tags: physics, math-history, mathematical-physics, translation-request

Neumann, Carl. “[Theoria nova phaenomenis electricis applicanda](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02419606).” *Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata* 2, no. 1 (August 1868): 120–128. doi:[10.1007/BF02419606](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02419606). p. 121:

> Nova introducitur suppositio, statuendo, causam illam motricem, quam
>   potentiale vocamus, ab altera massa ad alteram non subito sed
>   progrediente tempore transmitti, atque — ad instar lucis — per spatium
>   propagari celeritate quadam permagna et constante. Quam celeritatem
>   denotabimus litera $c$.
>
> Ista suppositio, conjuncta cum hac altera, principium Hamiltonianum
>   normam exprimere supremam ac sacrosanctam nullis exceptionibus obviam,
>   fit *suppositio in theoria nostra fundamentalis*, ex qua absque ulla
>   ulteriore suppositione leges illæ notissimæ a celⁱˢ Ampère, Neumann,
>   Weber, conditæ sua sponte emanabunt.

My translation attempt:

> A new supposition is introduced in making this motive cause, which we
>   call potential, not be immediately but gradually transmitted in time from one
>   mass to another, and—like light—to propagate with a great and constant
>   speed. We will denote this speed by the letter $c$.
>
> This supposition, together with the other, the supreme and sacrosanct
>   principle principle of Hamilton meeting no exceptions, is made
>   fundamental to our theory, from which (without any further
>   supposition) those well-founded laws of the celebrated
>    Ampère, Neumann, and Weber, on
>   their own foundations, will spontaneously emanate.

I'm particularly miffed regarding the last sentence (esp. the abbrevation "celⁱˢ" = "celebrandis" = celebrated/famous?). Did I translate it right?

thanks

Comment: Very wrong forum. Try the [appropriate one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't think HSM.SE (which currently has no translation-request tag) existed at the time I asked this question here; now it's too old to migrate.